# Problem based on Equation of straight lines.

Tags: analytic-geometry

Find the equations of a pair of straight lines which pass through the origin and are perpendicular to each of the lines represented by $ax^2+2hxy+by^2=0$.

I have already posted this question few days before but could not get answer. My book shows $bx^2-2hxy+ay^2=0$ as answer, but I didn't get that answer.

Comment: You are under the misapprehension that this site is a problem help-line.  It is _far_ more likely that you will get assistance here if you show _what_ you tried to do that "didn't work".  Questions that only give the statement of a problem with no discussion of what _you_ attempted to do are generally going to get down-voted and/or closed.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner  Fully agree, and yet people give full solutions !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y=m_1x$ & $y=m_2 x$ be the lines represented by  $ax^2+2hxy+by^2=0$ or $\frac{a}{b}x^2+\frac{2h}{b}xy+y^2=0$ then one should have $$(y-m_1x)(y-m_2x)=\frac{a}{b}x^2+\frac{2h}{b}xy+y^2 $$
$$m_1m_2 x^2-(m_1+m_2)xy+y^2=\frac{a}{b}x^2+\frac{2h}{b}xy+y^2$$
comparing the corresponding coefficient, one should get $$m_1m_2=\frac ab\tag 1$$
$$m_1+m_2=-\frac{2h}b\tag 2$$
Now, let $y=-\frac{x}{m_1}$ & $y=-\frac{x}{m_2}$ be the pair of lines perpendicular to the pair of lines: $ax^2+2hxy+by^2=0$ & passing through the origin then the combined equation is given as $$\left(y+\frac{x}{m_1}\right)\left(y+\frac{x}{m_2}\right)=0$$ 
$$x^2+(m_1+m_2)xy+m_1m_2y^2=0$$
setting the values of $m_1m_2$ & $(m_1+m_2)$ from (1) & (2), one should get 
$$x^2+\left(-\frac{2h}{b}\right)xy+\frac aby^2=0$$
$$\color{red}{bx^2-2hxy+ay^2=0}$$